# Finding imports and dependencies of a go program

Tags: go

The `go list -json` command run from the command line will tell you the imports and dependencies of a go program ( in json format). Is there a way to get this information from within a go program I.e at runtime, either by running the 'go list' command somehow or another way?

Comment: Critically: what do you want to do with that information?

Comment: @elithrar need to be able to log it while program is running (for domain specific reasons )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without using the go binary since go needs to analyze your source code.

It's pretty easy to do but it must have access to go and your source code at run time. Heres a quick example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "list", "-json")
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    var list GoList
    err = json.Unmarshal(stdout, &list)

    for _, d := range list.Deps {
        fmt.Printf(" - %s\n", d)
    }
}

type GoList struct {
    Dir        string
    ImportPath string
    Name       string
    Target     string
    Stale      bool
    Root       string
    GoFiles    []string
    Imports    []string
    Deps       []string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code uses the [go/build](http://godoc.org/go/build) to get the imports for the application in the current working directory.

```
p, err := build.Default.Import(".", ".", 0)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
for _, i := range p.Imports {
   fmt.Println(i)
}
```

You can build a list of all dependencies using a simple recursive function.

To get the imports for a specific `path`, use:

```
p, err := build.Default.Import(path, ".", 0)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
for _, i := range p.Imports {
   fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In what situations would the CWD not be set to source dir? I.e is it safe to assume that this is the likely default for all users in dev mode? Would you allow users to set it somehow?

Comment: Ok thank you so much. And no matter what the source directory is set at,  you expecting all this to break inside a binary as Volkers answer suggests? ( I don't have a project ready to test this in a binary and might indeed abandon now that I appreciate more the go env situation -never used binaries before :(

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this is possible without the source in a reliable way. Go binaries on different platforms, compiled with different compilers may or may not have (or may not have in the future) these informations compiled in.

But as Go programs are compiled anyway: Why not record this information while you do have access to the source code?

Comment: Want to be able to log it while program is running for domain specific reasons